# How to handle clicks in buttons left on screen but no longer valid, in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm a bit confused about something.  We are building a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework (v3 -- I know, I know, it's old, but that's what they want us to do) and at startup we offer the user th choice of two paths to follow, using buttons.  It works fine, but the buttons remain on the screen after the user has clicked, as is normal.  Should we attempt to handle a user click in the buttons after we have passed from their actual point of use?  That is, let's say we've passed through all our waterfalls and are back at the root dialog?  How we detect these clicks and intercept them and give suitable feedback (e.g. "That's not a valid choice"?).

At present, it seems there is some routing going on before the user click even gets to our root dialog --

```
> ChatConnector: message received. UniversalBot("*") routing <null> from
> "emulator" Library("BotBuilder").findRoutes() explanation:
>   ActiveDialog(0.1) ...BotBuilder:prompt-text - WARN: Prompt - no
> intent handler found for null ...BotBuilder:prompt-text -
> Session.send() ...BotBuilder:prompt-text - Session.sendBatch() sending
> 1 message(s)
```

A generic "I didn't understand. Please try again." reply is sent automatically, which seems to come from `botbuilder/systemResources.js`.  Is this, then, the correct and expect behaviour?

I'm a bit confused, as I thought the message would *always* get to the root dialog and we would have a chance to evaluate it there.  I've put a breakpoint in the root dialog, but it never reaches it when I click on an 'already used' button.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Can you provide the code that generates the buttons so we know what kind of buttons you're using, and also let us know what channel you're using?

Comment: When I return to work I'll see if I can -- it's proprietary.

Comment: You don't need to copy and paste the exact code. In fact, it's better not to. You should always create a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @KyleDelaney . Thanks -- apparently they have a solution worked out client-side here so I think for the moment I'm going to look at what they're doing and see if that will work.

Comment: I had asked what channel you're using. Are you now saying you're using your own custom Direct Line client (not Web Chat)?

Comment: @KyleDelaney -- The answer I got was that normally they use Web Chat.  I've just come into the project, and haven't used Bot Framework before, so it's new territory for me. Apparently the method they use client-side is to disable the buttons through the local history -- I don't know exactly what they mean by this (although I'll soon find out).  The buttons themselves are generally simply those of Adaptive Card forms which we're displaying.

Comment: I do tend to recommend client-side solutions when possible. Do you want to leave this question open until you get more information or do you want to accept waleed's answer and open a new question if needed?

Answer (score 2):

I've faced a similar scenario. I have several forms as adaptive cards and also a carousel of hero cards. What I do is make sure some of the data returned on buttons clicks (or taps) is unique for every form. Then when I'm expecting a form I check if it's the right one, otherwise anything else (including messages with no luis intents) is rejected and I ask the user to answer the current question or cancel while looping back a step.

So for example, in the data for this button

```
"actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Submit",
                "data": {
                    "x": 13
                }
            }
    ...
]
```

I would add "form" or maybe "dialog" with unique values that you can check for when you expect a specific form/card. In other places where I just expect text then I just ignore forms and re-ask the question.

I'm not how it works for NodeJs but in C#, buttons (and CardActions with MessageBack/PostBack) come under Context.Activity.Value whereas text responses are in Context.Activity.Text